# constructing a datatable with a foreign key

Tags: javascript, c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, razor-pages

If someone can help me with this one, I would really appreciate it.  I'm trying to get a Javascript table to display in a Razor pages application I'm writing.  It's mostly working, but I am having an issue with a column which has a foreign key.  The column is consistently coming up blank.  So, I'm using Visual studio 2019 community with .net core 3.2.
The misbehaving table looks like this
[image]

As you can see, the Category column is blank.  The main page has this code

```
<div class="col-12 border p-3">

<table id="DT_load" class="table table-sm table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>

            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Valuation</th>
            <th>Actions</th>


        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

```
</div>
@section Scripts
{

<script src="~/js/valuationsList.js"></script>

}
```

The javascript file that it calls is here:

```
var dataTable;


$(document).ready(function () {
loadDataTable();
});

function loadDataTable() {

dataTable = $('#DT_load').dataTable
    ({

        "ajax":
        {
            "url": "/api/valuations",
            "type": "GET",
            "datatype": "json"
        },
        "columns":
            [
              { "data": "date", "width": "30%" },
              { "data": "category", "width": "20%" },
                { "data": "valuation", "width": "15%" },
                {

                    "data": "id",
                    "render": function (data) {
                        return `
                     <div class="text-center">
                     <a href="/Valuations/Edit?id=${data}" class='btn btn-link text-blue' style='cursor:pointer; width:70px;'>
                         Edit
                     </a>
                     &nbsp;
                     <a href="/Valuations/Delete?id=${data}" class='btn btn-link text-blue' style='cursor:pointer; width:70px;'>
                         Delete
                     </a>

                     </div>`;
                    }, "width": "25%"
                }
            ],
        "language":
            {
            "emptyTable": "no data found"
        },
        "width": "100%"
    });
}
```

And the relevant method in the controller looks like this

```
        [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetAll()
    {
        return Json(new { data = await _context.CategoryValuations.ToListAsync() });
    }
```

Finally, the table I am trying to access looks like this:

[image]

and the category_id field is foreign keyed to the category table which looks like this:

[image]

If I use "category" in the javascript file, then the column is blank.  category_id returns an error.
Any help gratefully received.

Thanks in advance.

as per Sergey's comment.  Here are the classes.

First, the parent Category class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Investments10.Models
{
public partial class Category
{
    public Category()
    {
        CategoryPerformance = new HashSet<CategoryPerformance>();
        CategoryValuations = new HashSet<CategoryValuations>();
        TransferValuesTransferFrom = new HashSet<TransferValues>();
        TransferValuesTransferTo = new HashSet<TransferValues>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Category1 { get; set; }
    public bool InUse { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CategoryPerformance> CategoryPerformance {get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CategoryValuations> CategoryValuations { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TransferValues> TransferValuesTransferFrom { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TransferValues> TransferValuesTransferTo { get; set; }
}
}
```

And now the Category Valuations class which is foreign keyed to Category.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Investments10.Models
{
public partial class CategoryValuations
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public decimal Valuation { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this  action code:

```
  
    public async Task<JsonResult> GetAll()
    {
        return Json(new { data = await _context.CategoryValuations
                                  .Select( i=> new {
                                    id=i.Id,
                                    categoryId=i.CategoryId,
                                    date=i.Date,
                                    category=i.Category.Category1,
                                    valuation=i.Valuation
                                   })
                                  .ToListAsync() 
                        });
    }
```

Comment: Hi Sergey,  Thanks so much for your help.  I've pasted in the method.  When I run, 
I get a dialogue box that says "DataTables warning: table id=DT_load - Requested unknown parameter 'categoryId' for row 0, column 1. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4" If I click OK twice on the warning, it displays the table, but with the category column blank.

Comment: I added categoryId to query. Pls try again